# My PureComponent gets its state initialized when receive props from redux. Any clue?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

On props change from redux, component sets itself to its initial state.

```
componentDidUpdate()
```

also does not catch prevState correctly. Both changed and exisitng state becomes same.

I'm writing my component code below:

```
import React from 'react';

import { MaterialIcon } from '../icon';
import { ConfirmationButton } from '../confirmation';
import { ButtonColor } from '../button';
import {
  CustomGrid,
  CustomGridGap,
  CustomGridSize,
  InnerBox
} from '../../primitives';

import { Tabs } from './tabs';
import { TabsButtons } from './tabs-buttons';
import { TabsButton, TabsButtonView } from './tabs-button';
import { TabsButtonContainer } from './tabs-button-container';
import { TabsContent } from './tabs-content';
import { TabsTitle } from './tabs-title';
import style from './tabs.module.scss';

export type TabLabel = string | null;

export interface Identifiable {
  id?: string | number;
  // that something which can be used as alternative id if no provided from backend
  localId?: string | number;
}

export interface DataTabsProps<TabEntry extends Identifiable> {
  // the only thing which should drive changes
  data: TabEntry[];

  title?: string | JSX.Element;
  afterTabs?: string | JSX.Element;
  tabLabelFactory: (
    tabEntry: TabEntry,
    index: number
  ) => string | JSX.Element | React.ReactNode;
  newTabEntryFactory?: () => TabEntry;
  confirmationTemplate?: string | JSX.Element;
  isDeleteOnlyLocal?: boolean;
  onTabDelete?: (tabEntry: TabEntry, index: number) => void;
  children: (entry: TabEntry, index: number) => JSX.Element | null;
  addNewLabel?: string | JSX.Element;
  // if it's defined then we would have possibility of multiple tabs creation
  onAddTab?: () => void;
  emptyTabName?: string | JSX.Element;
  placeholder?: string | JSX.Element | null;
}

interface DataTabsState {
  selectedIndex: number;
}

export class DataTabs<
  TabEntry extends Identifiable
> extends React.PureComponent<DataTabsProps<TabEntry>, DataTabsState> {
  state = {
    selectedIndex: 0
  };
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(
    props: DataTabsProps<Identifiable>,
    { selectedIndex }: DataTabsState
  ) {
    const hasUncontrolledAddFeature = Boolean(props.newTabEntryFactory);
    const hasControlledAddFeature = Boolean(props.onAddTab);

    if (
      (hasUncontrolledAddFeature && selectedIndex > props.data.length) ||
      (hasControlledAddFeature && selectedIndex >= props.data.length)
    ) {
      return {
        selectedIndex: 0
      };
    }

    return null;
  }

  handleTabChange = (tabIndex: number) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedIndex: tabIndex
    });
  };

  handleTabAdd = () => {
    if (typeof this.props.onAddTab === 'function') {
      this.props.onAddTab();
      this.setState({
        selectedIndex: this.props.data.length
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { selectedIndex } = this.state;
    debugger;
    const {
      children,
      title,
      data,
      isDeleteOnlyLocal,
      newTabEntryFactory,
      tabLabelFactory,
      emptyTabName,
      onTabDelete,
      addNewLabel,
      afterTabs,
      onAddTab,
      confirmationTemplate,
      placeholder,
      ...rest
    } = this.props;
    const hasTitle = Boolean(title);
    const hasDelete = Boolean(onTabDelete);
    const hasAfterTabs = Boolean(afterTabs);
    const hasUncontrolledAddFeature = Boolean(newTabEntryFactory);
    const hasControlledAddFeature = Boolean(onAddTab);

    return (
      <Tabs active={selectedIndex} onChange={this.handleTabChange} {...rest}>
        <TabsButtonContainer>
          {hasTitle && (
            <InnerBox withSmallPadding={true} as={TabsTitle}>
              {title}
            </InnerBox>
          )}

          <TabsButtons>
            {data.map((tabEntry, index) => {
              const label = tabLabelFactory(tabEntry, index);
              const isLocalOnly = !tabEntry.id;

              return (
                <InnerBox
                  withSmallPadding={true}
                  as={TabsButton}
                  buttonIndex={index}
                  key={tabEntry.id || `${tabEntry.localId}-${index}`}
                >
                  <CustomGrid
                    columnCount={hasDelete ? 2 : 1}
                    columnSize={CustomGridSize.MAX_CONTENT}
                  >
                    {label || (
                      <span className={style.emptyTabName}>{emptyTabName}</span>
                    )}
                    {hasDelete &&
                      (!isDeleteOnlyLocal ||
                        (isDeleteOnlyLocal && isLocalOnly)) && (
                        <ConfirmationButton
                          onConfirm={() => onTabDelete!(tabEntry, index)}
                          color={ButtonColor.LINK}
                          confirmationTemplate={confirmationTemplate}
                          className={style.closeButton}
                        >
                          <MaterialIcon name="close" />
                        </ConfirmationButton>
                      )}
                  </CustomGrid>
                </InnerBox>
              );
            })}
            {/* in the future this scenario will be removed */}
            {hasUncontrolledAddFeature && (
              <InnerBox
                withSmallPadding={true}
                as={TabsButton}
                buttonIndex={data.length}
                data-test-el="add-new-tab-button"
              >
                {addNewLabel || (
                  <MaterialIcon className={style.addIcon} name="add" />
                )}
              </InnerBox>
            )}

            {hasControlledAddFeature && (
              <InnerBox
                withSmallPadding={true}
                as={TabsButtonView}
                onClick={this.handleTabAdd}
                data-test-el="add-new-tab-button"
              >
                <MaterialIcon name="add" />
              </InnerBox>
            )}
          </TabsButtons>

          {hasAfterTabs && <div>{afterTabs}</div>}
        </TabsButtonContainer>

        {data.map((tabEntry, index) => (
          <InnerBox
            as={TabsContent}
            tabIndex={index}
            withSmallPadding={true}
            key={tabEntry.id || `${tabEntry.localId}-${index}`}
          >
            {children(tabEntry, index)}
          </InnerBox>
        ))}

        {hasUncontrolledAddFeature && (
          <InnerBox as={TabsContent} tabIndex={data.length}>
            {children(newTabEntryFactory!(), data.length)}
          </InnerBox>
        )}

        {hasControlledAddFeature && !data.length && (
          <InnerBox as={TabsContent} tabIndex={0}>
            {placeholder}
          </InnerBox>
        )}
      </Tabs>
    );
  }
}
```

This component gets selectedIndex=0 when onSave() is provoked.
I'm unable to identify why this behavior is there as I've never faced it.

Comment: There are not enough information to help you

Comment: Some code might be useful--there's nothing here anyone can use to help.

Comment: @demkovych I've added code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with PureComponent you have to keep in mind that PureComponent prevent to reload the component if your props doesn't change. Which is awesome for performance. But also, can be an issue if you have a complex object as props. For some reasons it doesn't work. You probably should work with getDerivedStateFromProps and/or shouldComponentUpdade.

Take a look on those two methods they will help you